# Integrate widget in existing html without css conflict

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to integrate widget html file in a existing html page but i am getting many css issue after this. Is there any way that i can restrict css files of main html not to apply on widget html file.

```
**Sample html :**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="csstransforms" lang="ru" >
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <link href="abc.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="abc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>


<!-- WIDGET CODE-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="adidas" bb-api-url="https://adidas-dev.bookingbug.com">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <link href="def.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="defjs" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
.......widget html code
</body>
</html>



<body>
</html>
```

Comment: if there are common class then it will impact, tried by changing the class names in the widget's css files

Answer (score 0):

With HTML you are not allowed to have two HTML documents in a single file.

One approach to solve this is by using an iframe in your main HTML:

```
<iframe src="widget.html"></iframe>
```

So you create your widget in its own HTML file with its own styles and javascript scripts, and embed it in your main HTML file using the iframe (then your widget is completely isolated from your main HTML scripts and styles and not be affected by them).

Another approach will be to create a separate CSS for you widget and include it in your main HTML, then insert your widget's markup only (without the html and body tags) in your main HTML body.

In your widget CSS file you should create a "namespace" for you widget's style that will not collide with the rest of your CSS by doing something like this:

```
.my-widget-name {
     // your widget styles
 }
 .my-widget-name span.name {
    // your widget style 
 }
 .my-widget-name .box {
    // your widget style
 }
 .......
 .......
```

(I usually like to use something like LESS, but shown above is a traditional CSS example)

*"my-widget-name"* should be a unique class name that only your widget is using, and by sub-classing all of your widget styles under this class name, you are basically isolating it from the rest of your CSS.

Hope it helps a bit